# Wii remote extension connector doesn't detect nunchuk

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, nintendo-wii

I recently acquired a Wii Remote with built-in Motion Plus. Unfortunately, despite the second hand store (Cex) saying they had tested the controller, the extension connector doesn't seem to work with any of my otherwise healthy Nunchuks.

Is there a way of resetting the controller/Wii remote to see if this will fix the broken port, or is this typically indicative of hardware failure - despite all other functions of the Wii remote working without issue?

(if it is the latter, I will return it)

Comment: I've bought 2 used wiimotes with the built in Motion Plus and 2 nunchucks (all used) to use with my Wii U. Only one wiimote detects the nunchucks. One of the nunchucks seems to have issues even on the good wiimote. So in my personal experience, used Wii Remotes/nunchucks are basically a crap shoot.

Comment: @DangerZone bugger... even finding 2nd-hand Wii remotes for sale is a mission, let alone then knowing that they're pretty much faulty if you do 